# Undeclared Methods vs Categories in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-category

Imagine I have define a class MyClass as follows:

The class interface file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) NSString *myProperty;

- (void)myPublicMethod;

@end
```

The class implementation file using categories:

```
#import "MyClass.h"

@interface MyClass (MyCategory)

- (void)myPrivateMethod;

@end

@implementation MyClass

- (void)myPublicMethod {
    NSLog(@"myPublicMethod was called!");
    [self myPrivateMethod];
}

- (void)myPrivateMethod {
  NSLog(@"myPrivateMethod was called!");
}

@end
```

An alternative class implementation file NOT using categories:

```
#import "MyClass.h"

@ implementation MyClass

- (void)myPublicMethod {
    NSLog(@"myPublicMethod was called!");
    [self myPrivateMethod];

}

- (void)myPrivateMethod {
    NSLog(@"myPrivateMethod was called!");
}

@end
```

Was hoping someone could explain the difference between the two implementation file approaches.

Is it the case that using categories means the "private" methods are inherited by any subclasses of MyClass and not using categories means the "private" methods are *not* inherited by any subclasses?

Comment: no difference. (unless you are playing with low level ObjC api, which still may have no difference)

Comment: If I subclass MyClass where MySubclass is a subclass of MyClass. Interestingly, MySubclass cannot call myPrivateMethod of MyClass directly regardless of whether MyClass uses categories or not. This makes sense I guess as the public interface of MyClass declares only the one method myPublicMethod.

Answer (score 1):

**All methods that exist on a class are always inherited and are callable by anyone** regardless of how you declare them. The main difference is whether anybody knows about them. There was also a historic need to declare things before use which leads to internal forward declarations in older and old-style code.

---

A category is used to add methods to an existing class. A common use is to extend the functionality of one of the existing classes. For example you might implement:

```
@interface NSURL (HTTPQueryParameters)

- (NSDictionary *)httpQueryParameters;

@end
```

So from then on you've given `NSURL` itself the knowledge required to parse HTTP protocol query parameters. It's often the correct factoring to add functionality directly to classes you don't have the source for.

Objective-C used to follow the C rule that methods had knowledge only of those methods that had preceded them within the compilation unit. So to be able to call a method that appeared later in the source file you'd need a forward declaration. If you didn't want to publish that method for the world to see you could achieve that with a category or a class extension (which for this purpose is just an unnamed category).

Nowadays Objective-C methods can call any method that is defined anywhere within the compilation unit, including subsequently in the same source file. It's therefore now normal not to collect up your unpublished methods into a category or an extension just for the benefit of the compiler.

That leaves categories for:

- adding functionality to existing classes; and
- segmenting your classes if they become very large;

Class extensions are now primarily for:

- declaring `@property`s without publishing them.

---

In Objective-C any method call can be sent to any object — objects are dynamically typed. So there's a mapping table in memory at runtime for every class from method name to implementation. The lookup process is to see whether the method is implemented in the class dispatched to. If not then dispatch to the superclass. An exception will be raised if the runtime runs out of superclasses.

Comment: Man, I had forgotten that declaration/use order used to matter! That's a very good point. "Any message can be sent to any object" with the one restriction that ARC needs to have seen a method _with that name_ somewhere or it will error out.

Comment: @JoshCaswell you can still grab the `IMP` via the runtime or via `+ [NSObject instanceMethodForSelector]`, cast it to the correct number and format arguments and then call it C style. ARC will do the correct thing with the arguments.

Comment: @Tommy My previous comment (from playing around with Xcode) contradicts your comment that "All methods that exist on a class are always inherited and are callable by anyone regardless of how you declare them."

Comment: From Apple's Cocoa Core Competencies doco: "You can also use categories of your own classes to: 1) Distribute the implementation of your own classes into separate source files... 2) Declare private methods.

Comment: @user1433158 Apple is playing fast and loose with terminology. Declare a method that way, then use a `performSelector:` call elsewhere. You'll see that the method is perfectly callable (and you can then create a forward declaration to make it callable the ordinary way). This is specifically why Apple has to make it a licence term that private API may not be called: there's no technical barrier to doing so.

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of the method in a category `@interface` only serves to expose the method to users of the class, including -- as you mentioned in your comment -- subclasses.

(It would be much more usual to use a class extension (sometimes called an "anonymous category") declare a method that you're defining in the main implementation block. Actually, I'm not 100% sure what the interaction is between your category declaration and the main block definition -- I wouldn't have been surprised if it didn't compile, but it does.)

Thus, the only difference between your two examples is that the declaration allows you to create a private header in a situation where you want your own subclasses to access this method, but have framework users who you want to restrict.